# Get instagram followers count at a given date

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

Is there a way to retrieve the amount of followers that an instagram business page has at a given date?

Looking inside the [api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/insights), there is a field `follower_count` that returns the total number of new followers in each day within specified date range. But I want the total count, not the new ones.

If this information does not exists, how can I calculate it?

Comment: afaik it´s not possible, i needed this too recently and had to stick to getting new followers only.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query (replace `pageId` and `pageToken` with your own values) – it's working for me:

```
/{pageId}/insights?period=day&metric=page_follows&since=2023-10-01&until=2023-10-31&access_token={pageToken}
```

It's strange but this metric, `page_follows`, does not exist in the documentation.