# Is it possible to obtain the number of followers at a past point in time using the Instagram API?

Tags: instagram-graph-api

Is there an API available to retrieve the number of followers 7 days ago or 14 days ago from the acquisition date? As far as I've researched, I haven't been able to find a way to get the number of followers at any point in the past, so if anyone knows, please let me know.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55656903/get-instagram-followers-count-at-a-given-date?rq=2 Is this link helpful?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What exactly does {pageId} in your answer mean? Do you mean instagram_business_account? Do you mean app ID?

Comment: Also, do I have to do business verification to get the number of followers?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the instructions here, use request with input parameter **period**, **since** and **until**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/insights/

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/17841405822304914/insights?metric=follower_count&period=day&since=1501545600&until=1502493720&access_token=IGQVJ...
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. However, when I used it as a reference, it returned with no data stored in `data`. why is it
   "data": [
      
   ],

Comment: Which requests have you had success with?